# Message box if no radio button selected in c#?

Tags: c#, validation, radio-button, messagebox

Hi I was just wondering how to prompt an error if no radio button is selected? I am adding a lot of entries into a listview and I have it so you can select either Fixed or Zero (working with bonds) and I want that if neither is selected, a messagebox shows up. I tried:

```
if (rdbtn_Fixed == null && rdbtn_Zero == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select either Fixed or Zero coupon Type");
            return;
        }
```

But when I click the button to add to the listview, no error prompts up for some reason!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Damian

Comment: Just to give you further insight... `rdbtn_Fixed == null` would be checking whether or not the radio button had been initialised and created

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if radio is checked or not instead of checking if it is null. The radio button would not be `null` as they are being instantiated and wont be null. You can put condition on [**RadioButton.Checked**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked.aspx) property to check if radio button is selected.

```
if (!rdbtn_Fixed.Checked &&  !rdbtn_Fixed.Checked)
{
      MessageBox.Show("Please select either Fixed or Zero coupon Type");
      return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the controls `rdbtn_Fixed` and `rdbtn_Zero` are on your form/page, then, all else being equal, they won't be `null`; in order to determine if a `RadioButton` is selected you should use the apporiate property :[`RadioButton.Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked.aspx).